# ffmpeg creating a boomerrang video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to create a "boomerrang" video. Where it would take in one video, play that video forward, then play it backward, and once more forward all at 1.5x speed. I'm been able to do the forward/backwards process with this command:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex [0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat,setpts=0.5*PTS output/boomerrang.mp4`

But I've been unable to get that final 3rd play with the video playing forward. I'm assuming I would just need to concat the video on the end but I'm not really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the original input to the concat.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex [0]reverse[r];[0][r][0]concat=n=3,setpts=0.5*PTS output/boomerrang.mp4
```